# Http Request and iFrame issue in SalesForce, INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY

Tags: angularjs, servlets, iframe, permissions, salesforce

Here is my issue, I created an app in SalesForce and it works great for me. I have administrator privileges, in this app I have an iFrame that references the SF, servlet file reader, when I call it when login as an admin it works great but when I try with a standard user I get the following error:

> Refused to display 
>           'https://myDomain.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00PG000000UCL0CMAX'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

SO that's the first issue, the second is with the Http request, I am creating an attachment with AngularJS via the Http request, again it works fine when logged in as an admin but for standard users I get the following error:

> POST
>   https://myDomain.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Attachment/
>   400 (Bad Request)

For this particular piece I was configuring the http request as follow:

```
app.run(['$http', '$window', function($http, $window) {

    /*Get the '{!GETSESSIONID()}' value cannot be processed on static ressource, 
            hence the link to the window global variable.*/
    var sessionId = $window.__sfdcSessionId;

    $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $http.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];

    /* In order for this to work the domain has to be white-listed within
            SalesForce security Settings > CORS */
    $http.defaults.headers.common["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
    $http.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
    $http.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    //Session ID necessary for authentication purposes.
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "OAuth " + sessionId;
    $http.defaults.headers.common['X-User-Agent'] = "MyClient";
}]);
```

Again it works fine for Admins but not for Standard Users.
Any thoughts, I assume it has something to do with permission but I obviously don't want to give admin privileges to everyone...I am not sure where the issue really stems from, any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** Looking through the network call I was able to get a more accurate error concerning the Bad Request:

> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY

[image: Network Request and Responsee]

So I know this has to do with permissions but can't figure out, exactly what to do different to make it work for all users and not just admins... Any suggestions?

I attached the actual AngularJS function that makes the call:

attachment.save = function(base64value, document) {

```
    /*Stripping the file type text in front of the base64 
        string, without this the file would show as corrupted */
    var position = base64value.indexOf("base64,");
    var matchWord = "base64,";
    var base64valueClean = base64value.slice(position + matchWord.length, base64value.length);

    //Setting payload to be saved in SF database.
    var data = {
        "Body": base64valueClean,
        "ContentType": document.attachmentContentType,
        "ParentId": document.id,
        "Name": document.fileName
    };

    var requestHeaders = {
            'Timeout': '600',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $window.__sfdcSessionId
        };


    /*Get the {!URLFOR('/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Attachment/')} value
        cannot be processed on static ressource, hence the link to the window
        global variable.*/
    var url = $window.__url;
    var method = 'POST';

    /* May be useful in future
    //Allows this function to be used for updates as well as insert
    var isUpdate = ($.trim(document.attachmentId) !==);
    if (isUpdate) {
        url = url + document.attachmentId;
        method = 'PATCH';
    } else {
        // Method for creation
        method = 'POST';
    };*/

    //Request system data
    var request = {

        url: url,
        method: method,
        data: data,
        requestHeaders: requestHeaders

    };

    console.log(request);

    //Promise type approach to Http request, allows easy handle of succes and failure
    // Very useful for asynchronous calls.
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    //Performing http request to Server
    $http(request).then(function(response) {

        deferred.resolve(response);
        console.log('File UPLOADED to SF!');

    }, function(event) {

        //Need to Improve error handling!!!
        deferred.reject('The attachment could not be saved:' + event);

    });


    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, all this came down to permissions within the Profile. Users did not have read and write permission for the parent object that was associated with this attachment.

I changed it and now it works like a charm...Not nearly as convoluted as I thought the answer would be!